# How to scale SVG using CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, inline

Is possible to scale SVG using CSS? I use `<img>` to insert an SVG icon in HTML. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/kw5fuw7L/.

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #202125;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #2C2E32;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}    

nav ul li.active {
    background: #F5A623;
}

svg path {
    fill: #fff !important;
}

nav ul li .svg-container {
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
}

nav ul li img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul li span {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 120px;
    text-indent: -5000em;
}
```

Unfortunately, I have to use this code too: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/wuSF7/, to give them color. It works okay before I put there this script.

I would be grateful if someone have idea how to scale an SVG icons.

Comment: What about using CSS transforms? Scaling SVG's with transforms works perfectly because there is no resolution loss.

Comment: SVG's are a tricky think. When they're an SVG element they basically become a document and have some of the features of a document like it's artboard (viewBox). Here's a variation I mucked around with: http://jsfiddle.net/wuSF7/353/ See this article for more details: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: If you want to scale the whole thing just set width and height CSS properties on the img element

Comment: @RobertLongson he needs to convert it to inline SVG first (see the fiddle)

Comment: Not if he wants to scale the whole thing. I'm not really sure what he wants though even when I've looked at the fiddle.

Comment: @RobertLongson with "wole thing" you mean svg-container? It works, but not in this case, since they all have different size. Thank you very much for help!

Comment: You can size each container differently, give them an id and target the CSS to the id.